# How to connect LED tape strips in separate locations to one power source?

Tags: kitchens, led

We're looking into running LED Tape Lights under the wall cabinets in our kitchen.  We have three sections that would get the lights and we need them all powered by a single switch.  There is a switch that goes up into the attic in the middle of the kitchen where we used to have a light so that's not a problem.

In the linked picture, the RED lines are where the LED Tapes would go.  The cooktop is in the gap at the top and a window is over the sink.  There's no way to run something across the openings so I think I need to run three separate lines down from the attic.
Pic: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2rsyzpnbw2qf3jr/led%20tape.jpg?dl=0

[image: linked image]

The length of the actual LED sections are approximately 14", 100", & 12".  Each run would also have to come down from the attic to the bottom of the cabinets...

The two ways I could think of are:

1) Using one Tape power supply in the attic and then splitting it off to go to the three areas for tapes.  Not sure how long I can run things from a single power supply
2) Using one power supply for each section of tape (or maybe one for the long section and a second one for the short ones?)

I've never used the LED Tape lights before so just wanted to get some basic feedback before I heard to the store and stare at the options hanging on the racks.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you're using really cheeseball power supplies, one should be ample to handle a few metres of LED strip, so you should be able to power it all from one PS.   Now, will you want dimming?

Comment: LED "tape" do not last very long.   For starters, the "sticky" stops being "sticky" after a while.  But more importantly, if you're running them alot, the LED's overheat and fail.  (There is no heat-sinking built into those tapes)   The whole strip will be quite dim in a year or two.   If you're just throwing something up quick, maybe that doesn't matter to you.  But if you're doing a many-hours-long project, you would be best served to buy actual engineered fixtures with proper thermal considerations taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either one power supply or many. The important thing is that you use a power supply that is listed for enclosing in a wall or attic. Something like in this picture: [image]

Any light strip you buy that is designed for permanent installation should come with such a supply and will be listed by UL or similar.

I don't recall seeing LED tape strips that come with a proper wall box, rather I have seen them come with plug in power supplies or transformers that most municipalities will not allow to be buried in a wall. It doesn't mean they don't exist, of course. Regardless, check with your code office to see what supply is permitted in your area. Perhaps they will allow a simple transformer to be concealed. That would surprise me, though.

Answer (score 1):

First look into the safety aspect. What is the operating voltage of that LED strip? If it is 12V DC type not much concern but some tape light are made to run on 110/240 AC. The following recommended method is suitable for low voltage DC strip light.

What you can do it simply cut it into pieces according to your lengths but make sure the cut is made on the cuttable locations on the strip. Then simply relink them using extension wires which are suitable for the current rating. Normally 0.5mm² wires will be the right choice.

You got nothing much to worry about electrical insulation safety for DC system but be sure the wiring won't be wet by possible water sipping from above.

One power supply should suffice for this. Just feed the power from one end of the strip.

Answer (score 0):

You could wire them in series or in parallel.  Just be sure that the power supply is matched to your wiring, and large enough for the load.  If you take one long tape and cut it up into 3 lengths, you will need to wire them in series, as the parallel approach will not work with one power supply.  The AC/DC comments by soosai steven should be considered as well.

Comment: 90% of LED tape cannot be wired in series, they have dropping resistors for each LED. The expensive (constant current) strips can be used in series like that, but they are the exception.